# React-Hook-Form validation API called multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using React-Hook-Form for a signup page where a user inputs a username, email and password. For the form validation I have created a custom validation class. As part of the `username` validation I make an API call to check that the username is not already in use. The form validation works for the `username` field, however when I tab down to the `email` field an API call to check for a duplicate `username` is made for every keystroke in the `email` field. The same problem occurs when inputting into the `password`field. I have the validation mode set to `onBlur` but it appears that the validation function is being called `onChange`, even when it's validating a different property?

```
export default function Signup() {

    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm<SignupRequest>({
        mode: "onBlur",
        reValidateMode: "onBlur"
    });


    const onSubmit = (data: SignupRequest) => {
        //createNewUser(data);
    };


    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} >
                <div className="mt-4 mb-3">
                    <label className="form-label">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" {...register("username", { validate: ValidationService.ValidateUsername })} />
                    {errors.username && <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.username?.message}</div>}
                </div>

                <div className="mt-4 mb-3">
                    <label className="form-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" {...register("email", { validate: ValidationService.ValidateEmail })} />
                    {errors.email && <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.email?.message}</div>}
                </div>

                <div className="mt-4 mb-3">
                    <label className="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" {...register("password", { validate: ValidationService.ValidatePassword })} />
                    {errors.password && <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.password?.message}</div>}
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-dk-blue w-100">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}



export class ValidationService {
    static async ValidateUsername(username: string) {
        if (username.trim() === "") {
            return "Username is required"
        }

        if (username.length < 3) {
            return "Username must be at least 3 characters"
        }

        if (username.length > 12) {
            return "Username cannot exceed 12 characters"
        }

        if (!(/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test(username))) {
            return "Username can only contain letters & numbers"
        }

        // make api call to check if username is already in use
        const response = await UserService.UsernameExists(username);
        if (response?.successful) {
            const usernameExists = response?.data
            if (usernameExists) {
                return "Username is already in use"
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return "Username is already in use"
        }
    }

    static ValidateEmail(email: string) {
        if (email.trim() === "") {
            return "Email is required"
        }

        if (!(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test(email))) {
            return "Invalid email format"
        }

        return true;
    }

    static ValidatePassword(password: string) {
        if (password.trim() === "") {
            return "Password is required"
        }

        if (password.length < 8) {
            return "Password must be at least 8 characters"
        }

        if (password.length > 128) {
            return "Password cannot exceed 128 characters"
        }

        if (!(/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#$%&*+?:]).{8,128}$/.test(password))) {
            return "Password must contain at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, one number and one special character"
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```